# Which answer to accept when two answers are both correct and extremely helpful?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I have asked this question: [How to make automatic line numbers next to an html text box with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378371/how-to-make-automatic-line-numbers-next-to-an-html-text-box-with-javascript)

I got two answers, one roughly two hours before the other, both correct and extremely helpful. One of them thoroughly explained a concept with examples, and the other wrote up an entire solution (mostly correct).

Both answers helped me a lot. I only have one green check-mark, however I feel that both answers deserve it. How should I reward the green checkmark?

Comment: Flip coin.  Rock/paper/scissors.  So many techniques...

Comment: You don't appear to have upvoted either of the "extremely helpful" answers yet.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was going to wait until after I gave the checkmark before upvoting.