# Which answer should I accept?

Tags: support

I like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222417/308851 more because it contains all the information I need however https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222473/308851 is much more researched and detailed. Which one should I accept?

Comment: The one you like more.

Comment: So it's subjective?

Comment: Yes. The checkmark means just that: OP liked that answer best.

Comment: This site is not about liking things, you pick the one that is the most relevant to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer hrm, OK. This is not a duplicate though because both of these explanations are perfectly acceptable I just liked the more succinct one better.

Comment: Uo, I am the author of one of the answers. Some comment would've helped to understand why you unaccepted mine and accepted the other one. Anyway, just feel free to accept the one that addresses your specific problem better, which I do think is [Tom Fenech's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39222417/1983854).

Comment: This does get asked a lot. There are multiple duplicates to pick from: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320366/which-answer-to-accept-when-two-answers-are-both-correct-and-extremely-helpful, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294784/two-good-answers-complete-each-other-but-which-one-should-be-rather-accepted are a couple of other examples. If they're both equally helpful and equally correct, then it's basically just a flip of a coin. Be sure to upvote both answers to indicate that they are both useful.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294784/two-good-answers-complete-each-other-but-which-one-should-be-rather-accepted is the duplicate Cody Gray is right.